# com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 6: Passphrase required

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

This error occurs when signing in to my app using Firebase.ui.auth and google sign-in, unable to get data from firestore too because of the error. the code worked fine until yesterday.

```
com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Error when saving credential.
    at com.firebase.ui.auth.viewmodel.smartlock.SmartLockHandler$1.onComplete(SmartLockHandler.java:98)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 6: Passphrase required.
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zai.zaf(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zaj.onComplete(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zaa(Unknown Source:172)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(Unknown Source:131)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BaseImplementation$ApiMethodImpl.setResult(Unknown Source:36)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzo.zzc(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzv.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:9)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzd.onTransact(Unknown Source:12)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

***Code:***

```
List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build(),
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build(),
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
            );

            startActivityForResult(

                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                            .build(),1
            );

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                if (response.isNewUser())
                {
                    String username = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();

                    Intent userintent = new Intent(this,UserActivity.class);
                    userintent.putExtra("userName",username);
                    startActivity(userintent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent timelineIntent = new Intent(this, TimelineActivity.class);
                    timelineIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(timelineIntent);
                }

            } else {

                if (response.getError().getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.PROVIDER_ERROR)
                    finish();

                if (response == null)
                    finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

***SmartLockHandler.java***

Below is the file where error occurs according to Log

[SmartLockHandler.java](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/viewmodel/smartlock/SmartLockHandler.java)

Comment: Please share the code that produces this error.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/viewmodel/smartlock/SmartLockHandler.java . updated the question  @AlexMamo